# How to use HM-10/HC-08 in AT command mode?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I have bought HM-10 but its name is showing HC-08. I want to know how will i use it in AT mode. I have arduino mega. I am using HC-05 in AT mode by setting 34th(key) pin high.

Answer (score 0):

For HM-10 or HC-08 there are several AT commands lists (access via serial).

For example for the HC-08:

---

- AT responds OK

---

- AT + BAUDx responds with OKn where x is 1 - n is 1200, 2 - 2400, 3 -
  4800, 4 - 9600 (default), 5 - 19200, 6 - 38400, 7 - 57600, 8 -
  115200.

**Note:** module must be reset after power-on for the new serial port baud rate to take effect.

---

- AT + NAME name responds OKsetname - name is the Bluetooth device name to be set and must be 13 characters or fewer. Retained across power offs.

**Note:** module must be reset after power-on for the new device name to take effect.

---

You can find complete lists if you search to "HC-08 AT commands list" in the web.